# Remote Procedure Calls vs. Local Procedure Calls

Tags: rpc

What are the differences between RPC (Remote Prpcedure Calls) and LPC (Local Procedure Calls)?

Comment: One is remote and the other one is local...!? Please provide some more context in which you encountered these terms, and what's unclear about them.

Comment: RPC is inter-process communication technique that allows client and server software to communicate in a distributed environment.LPC is to be used for communication between two user mode processes. I want to know more differences between these two.

Comment: LPC - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Procedure_Call && RPC - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Read their respective Wikipedia pages:

RPC - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call

LPC - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Procedure_Call

Everything is explained there. First put some effort into it and if you get stuck you can still pose a non-trivial questions.

Differences:

- RPC is slower than LPC since it uses the network to invoke the method.
- With RPC the procedure call can be executed on a remote machine which can be addressed in several ways.
- The parameters and return value need to be serializable (to use java terminology).
- RPC's can fail due to network issues.
- RPC's need to be set up before using them.
- The language used to call the remote procedure and the language implementing the remote procedure are not necessarily the same.
- and more.

Comment: Ditto on the effort. At least quote some relevant passages from those pages, don't just link to them. This is a comment at best, not an answer.

Comment: This is also a vague question which cannot be answered in a finite amount of time nor will the answer be useful to anyone. I added some differences as the question asks.

Comment: Agreed. Some things simply cannot and should not be answered.

Comment: Let's hope the question is edited to be useful. I will modify my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In RPC, programs can be executed from a different computer while in LPC, programs are executed by the host computer.